# CSS Opacaity on right?

Tags: css, opacity

I'm curious is there any CSS able to make opacity on right side?

```css
.test {
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Testing</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using pseudo elements:

Just create two pseudo elements (`:before`/`:after`). Absolutely position them *relative* to the parent element. Give them a width of `50%`, and specify opacity on one.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/djzsrv43/)

```css
.test {
    width: 300px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.test:before, .test:after {
    content: '';
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.test:before {
    left: 0;
}
.test:after {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Testing</div>
```

---

#### Using [CSS3 linear-gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

Alternatively, you could also use [CSS3 linear-gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient). In this case:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #000 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%);
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vk0fdyzf/)

```css
.test {
    width: 300px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #000 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Testing</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS gradients anytime. They are easy to use and can be made very easily.